# AngularJs: simple like system

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to increment a variable within a ng-repeat loop on click?

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="post in posts">
...
... 
<button ng-click="postLike(post.like_count)">Like {{post.like_count}}</button>
...
...
</li>

$scope.postLike = function(likeCount) {
    //likeCount++
}
```

I could probably use `$scope.$apply` somehow but how do I know exactly which variable to increment?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ng-click="postLike(post)">Like {{post.like_count}}</button>

$scope.postLike = function(post) {
    post.like_count += 1;
};
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the reason why this works is you are passing a reference type to the function and changing it, where the question was passing a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

a way of doing that would be the following:

```
<button ng-click="postLike($index)">Like {{post.like_count}}</button>

$scope.postLike = function(i) {
    $scope.posts[i].like_count += 1;
};
```

and you can alter the values in the posts array directly.